# In Ubuntu which tool we use for disk-defragment?

Tags: application-development, tools

Can Ubuntu have any disk-defragment tools, like Microsoft Windows.

Or any other tools equivalent for it?

I read: [Defragmenting tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137707/defragmenting-tools-on-ubuntu-for-non-ext-formats)

Comment: What disk formats do you want to defrag? (e.g. NTFS, ext2, etc).There already are a few similar question to this - e.g. [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/247635/178596). However, I think if you slightly resize a disk in GParted (reduce the size by a few megabytes), it defrags it anyway (I think there is a question and answer somewhere on how to defrag stuff anyway....).

Comment: @Wilf ohh! that good. strange info. And today I know why my Ubuntu still work good and fast only 200 MB free space reaming. no slow no crash! good info..

Comment: If you want to free space you can `baobab` (disk usage analyzet) to find what is using it, and remove large unneeded stuff. Is the lack of free space why you want to defrag the disk? - trying to defrag with limited free space may cause problems.

Comment: @Wilf  just ask it for curiosity... I shock Linux is working very nice  with very limited space also.  Thanks for info. Defrag is good for only windows. I just say for it,... Linux Rock!!!